# How do we set alerts for Announcement List or any lists for SharePoint groups

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, wss-3.0, alert

As we all know how to set user alerts for lists in sharepoint 2007, wss 3.0. I was wondering if it is possible to set alert to sharepoint group. So that when new item is added into the list, users in the respective groups assigned can get alerts.

I tryed using group but people picker does not identify group names. I want to set alert to all staff group(800 users) for a urgent announcements. How do i perform this without adding one user at a time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint can configure alerts only for Windows Groups. Follow these steps:

1. Create a SharePoint Group and make sure is **E-mail enabled**, as a
   result this will create a Distribution List in AD (also makes sure the domain group has at visitor permissions on the list that are you are creating the alerts for - you might end up with BOTH the SharePoint and AD Group having permissions - leave them both!!)
2. In AD, change properties of the newly created group to Group Type =
   Security. This is because only security groups will show up in
   SharePoint's people picker as Domain Groups.
3. Then setup the alert and use the address book to locate the domain
   group. In the address book you'll see it with the form "DOMAIN\group
   name".

On list having approval turned on you need to approve items before the alerts are sent.

As alternative you could envision a simple SPD 2010 Workflow to send notification emails, if you only target just few lists, using the "Wait for a change..." activity and looking for the "Approval Status" property (if Content Approval is enabled) or simply have the workflow send email to a group of people upon Item Creation.

Or use something free on CodePlex (used to work for MOSS 2007) http://advancedalert.codeplex.com/

[image]

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Comment: C.Marius thank you very much for your suggestion. I have a question about point 1. How do we email enable Sharepoint Group. As mentioned (also makes sure the domain group has at visitor permissions on the list that are you are creating the alerts for - you might end up with BOTH the SharePoint and AD Group having permissions - leave them both!!). What do you mean by Domain Group is it Sharepoint Group one we created you are referring to ?. Thank You

Comment: 1. Upon SP Group creation you have the chance to specify a Email address.
2. Once you change AD settings from Distribution List to Security Group it will also be available for selection in People picker just as any user.

Comment: So that means i first gotta create  AD Group(Security Group). Then add  same group in Sharepoint as a user  and assign email address for that group?

Comment: Is simpler to go from SP direction: create your SP Group, specify email to it - while in SharePoint still, then change attributes in AD, less operations.

Comment: Where do i specify email in sharepoint Group Creation: Where it says " Send membership requests to the following e-mail address:##########".

Comment: http://prequest01.wordpress.com/2008/10/28/send-email-to-all-users-of-a-sharepoint-group/